# How to use UiHint and jQuery function For multiple inputs?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-uihint

I have an model that named mymodel and include this

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name{get;set;}
    [UIHint("_ViewDate")]

    public string date { get; set; }
}
```

Data View Page :

```js
  @section scripts
    {

                <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
                <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

                <script src="~/Scripts/MdBootstrapPersianDateTimePicker/jalaali.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

                <script src="~/Scripts/MdBootstrapPersianDateTimePicker/jquery.Bootstrap-PersianDateTimePicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>




    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#txt').MdPersianDateTimePicker({
            Placement: 'bottom', // default is 'bottom'
            Trigger: 'focus', // default is 'focus',
            EnableTimePicker: true, // default is true,
            TargetSelector: '', // default is empty,
            GroupId: '', // default is empty,
            ToDate: false, // default is false,
            FromDate: false, // default is false,
        });
    </script>
    }
```

```css
  @section head
    {
        <meta charset="utf-8" />

        <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="~/Content/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="~/Content/jquery.Bootstrap-PersianDateTimePicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    }
```

```html
<dt>
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.date)
</dt>

<dd>
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.date)
</dd>
<dd>
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.date)

</dd>
<dd>
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.date)

</dd>
```

**and _ViewDate Partial View that called by UIHint**

```js
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#txt').MdPersianDateTimePicker({
            Placement: 'bottom', // default is 'bottom'
            Trigger: 'focus', // default is 'focus',
            EnableTimePicker: true, // default is true,
            TargetSelector: '', // default is empty,
            GroupId: '', // default is empty,
            ToDate: false, // default is false,
            FromDate: false, // default is false,
        });
    </script>
```

```html
@model  string


<div class="form-actions">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Date..." class="text-primary" id="txt" />

</div>
```

Now,the problem is when load Date view page my action executed for an object only and no execute again.